# Synchronize modification between SWT table and TextEditor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, text-editor, jface

I'm facing a problem and want to ask for a solution.

I'm working on an eclipse plugin project, in which an editor for a type of resource file is required. The resource file has similar structure like CSV file. My idea is to provide user the option to edit this type of file both in plain text format and also in an SWT table. Plain text is required for examining data and table provides more flexibility to editing such as sorting by column.

I have been able to create a `MultiPageEditorPart`, with one page of `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor`, and another page with a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table` and several other widgets like search bar. The content of the resource file can be shown in the `TextEditor`, can also be edited and saved. On the other hand, the content can be loaded in the table too, sorting and searching all work good.

The problem is: when I edit a cell in the table, I want the change also reflected in the `TextEditor`, and vice versa. Since the resource file can be very large, I want the saving action happen only on the `TextEditor`, i.e. I don't want any modification in the table directly stored to resource file, but to mark the file dirty, but I can't figure out how. How can I for example get the content of `EditorInput`, check it line by line, and modify it outside `TextEditor`?

Or, are there more efficient ways to do this? Can anyone give any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IDocument` used by the `TextEditor` gives you access to the document contents. Get this with something like:

```java
IDocumentProvider provider = editor.getDocumentProvider();

IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();

IDocument document = provider.getDocument(input);
```

`IDocument` has many methods for accessing lines such as:

```java
int getLineOffset(int line);

int getLineLength(int line);
```

and methods for modify the text:

```java
void replace(int offset, int length, String text);
```